# Filling Temporary Table From Stored Procedure Using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to populate a predefined temporary table with the results of a stored procedure that executed using dynamic SQL. This temporary table is inside of another stored procedure and is returned as part of the result set once it is filled. The code to create the table and insert the data is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
    As_Of_Date DATE NULL,
    Fund VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Code VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Amount FLOAT NULL
);

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'INSERT INTO #MyTable
                          EXEC [dbo].[p_UI_Get_My_Tables_Data] ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, As_Of_Date, 23) + ''', ''' + @Fund + ''';'
FROM #AsOfDates;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

SELECT *
FROM #MyTable
ORDER BY Fund, Code, As_Of_Date;
```

The final statement in `p_UI_Get_My_Tables_Data` looks like this:

```
SELECT
    @AsOfDate AS As_Of_Date, Fund, Code, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM        
    #DetailedData
GROUP BY    
    Fund, Print_Group;
```

I have tried executing this code from both my application and SQL Server and usually get an error that says

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

I have reviewed the code and tried running `p_UI_Get_My_Tables_Data` by itself and as far as I can tell the table is being returned in the correct format. However, there is one thing that I find strange.

If I open a new query in SQL Server and run my main stored procedure first, I will get the error. However, if I run `p_UI_Get_My_Tables_Data` by itself first, then my main stored procedure will start working properly. It will continue to work for a little while in SQL Server, but will always fail when called from my application.

I have tried other methods of getting the data I need, but none of them were satisfactory. I tried switching `@MyTable` to a global temporary table but got the same error. I cannot use a table function because `p_UI_Get_My_Tables_Data` uses temporary tables. I gave `OPENROWSET` a shot but starting running into configuration errors and decided it wasn't the best solution.

I think there's a way to accomplish what I am trying to do, since it works part of the time, but I must be missing something in terms of why it is fails at other times. Any advice someone can offer would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** one thing that did work, but is obviously not ideal, was running `p_UI_Get_My_Tables_Data` from my application and ignoring the results and then running the actual stored procedure. This is the same approach I used to make it work in SQL Server, but I have no idea why it is necessary and would prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As far as I can tell, the column names and number match, otherwise it would not work even with the workaround I described. The procedure works correctly when executed with the same parameters outside of the dynamic SQL. I do not believe there should be any issues with identify columns with the data I am using.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL at all?

Comment: I did not realize I could use the looping approach recommended by Dale below and thought this was my best way of executing the procedure one time for a variable amount of dates. I will be using that approach in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you are using Dynamic SQL, doesn't the following do the job:

```
declare @TempTable table (As_Of_Date varchar(10), Done bit default(0));
declare @As_Of_Date varchar(10);

insert into @TempTable
  select CONVERT(VARCHAR, As_Of_Date, 23)
  from #AsOfDates;

while exists (select 1 from @TempTable where Done = 0) begin
  select top 1 @As_Of_Date = As_Of_Date from @TempTable
  INSERT INTO #MyTable
    EXEC [dbo].[p_UI_Get_My_Tables_Data] @As_Of_Date, @Fund;
  update @TempTable set Done = 1 where @As_Of_Date = As_Of_Date
end
```

Comment: I tried this with both the table variable and a temporary table and got the same "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" error as before. The workaround I used for the dynamic SQL version did not work with this approach. I did not do this initially because I had seen a lot of examples with people using cursors and other people saying not to. This approach seems better though. Would this generally perform better than dynamic SQL in cases where I wasn't experiencing an error?

Comment: If you are getting an error with this approach then there is a real mismatch between your table definitions. Either there is a datatype match, or you have an accidental select earlier in your SP. Assuming my code does what you want (when its working) its a far better approach than using dynamic sql.

Comment: Given you said it works `sometimes` with your dynamic sql, are you sure you don't have an additional select in your SP that only runs under an error condition? The way to debug this is get it working with a shell SP first with no logic in it, then build it up.

Comment: If there was a real mismatch, then why would the dynamic SQL version work if I run the procedure being called by the dynamic SQL once before running the dynamic SQL? I will probably rewrite some other code to use this approach instead of dynamic SQL, so thank you for sharing it with me.

Comment: The sometimes is not random. It is completely reproduceable. I will check the code again to make sure there are no errant selects, but there's not much logic in the SP being called.

Comment: Well there has to be something fishy with your code somewhere :) because in principle the mechanism should work (I've done similar stuff before) therefore the issue is in the specifics of how you are doing it. Nothing you have posted points to an error, so it must be lurking in the nested SP.